# Add commit author as sender for hook/post

Tags: git, bash, githooks

When someone makes a commit, I want the author to be set as the sender.  I've narrowed down this piece of code in `post-receive`

```
send_mail()
{
        if [ -n "$envelopesender" ]; then
                /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -f "$envelopesender"
        else
                /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
        fi
}
```

And I was to add it to the else condition, I think with something like

```
git log <SHA-1> --pretty=format:"%an<%ae>" -1
```

And I think I would use the `$newrev` variable for the sha.

I'm not so fresh on my [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).  How can I make this happen?

Comment: If you use the committer address as the envelope sender, that address will get any reports about undeliverable messages. Since it's likely that the developers won't be able to do anything about obsolete addresses on the distribution list this may not be a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this I presume:

```
send_mail()
{
    if [ -n "$envelopesender" ]; then
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -f "$envelopesender"
    else
        author="$(git --no-pager show -s --pretty="%an" $newrev)"
        email="$(git --no-pager show -s --pretty="%ae" $newrev | sed 's/ *$//g')"
        if [ -n "$email" ]; then
            /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -F "$author" -f "$email"
        fi
    fi
}
```

For [`git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html):

- `git show` looks like a more appropriate command to extract information about the commit rather than `git log`. (There might be something even more appropriate that you could use ;) )
- `--no-pager` ensures it does not open up the pager program
- `-s` skips the list of files and differences in the commit

For [`sendmail`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail):

- Set the sender name using `-F`
- Set the sender email using `-f`

Comment: I looks like some posts don't have commits, and therefor, no author.  Is there a way I could add another condition to check that `$email` isn't empty/null?

Comment: @SteveRobbins - have updated the answer with an additional checking for the email being non-empty. The sed is optional, but helps to strip out any trailing whitespaces which might trigger a false positive.